# What user should own /var/www/html in Centos?

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, permissions

I've installed CentOS 5.5 with apache, php and mysql.

Right now the `/var/www/html` directory is owned by the root while apache is being run by apache user from apache group.

Is that recommended? Should I `chown` the html directory to another user such as `wwwuser:wwwgroup`?

Comment: Why? Are you going to have the web server write to it?

Comment: wait....no... well...i'm confused. I guess the right way to ask this question will be:         Should my website that will be in html directory be owned by root or some other user?

Comment: If you read up a bit on *nix permissions then you'll be in a better place to ask this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Generally speaking, a web server's user should not have write access to anything, particularly not if it is running dynamic systems like PHP.

Apache achieves privilege separation by having the sensitive bits operate from a master process running as root, which the children can send log events to and get configuration from. The children run as unpriviliged users that should only read stuff.